# Como abrir uma URL passando parâmetro oculto?

Tags: delphi

Preciso, via Delphi, abrir uma Url/Site passando um parâmetro oculto (que não seja mostrado na Url).

Tentei o ShellExecute:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'Open', 'http://localhost:49486/admin/Login.aspx?View={1B605F4E-A7C9-4B7B-98B7-5A2D2ADBD520}', nil, nil, 1);
```

Porém ele apenas permite passar o parâmetro via url, ficando visível.

Comment: Você quer fazer uma requisição POST. Isso?

Comment: Se você vai realizar a requisição através da linguagem e não pelo front-end, qual a necessidade de os parâmetros não ficarem "visíveis"?

Comment: Exato @jbueno. Preciso abrir a URL com um parâmetro Post.

Comment: Kenny no sistema em Delphi, terá um atalho para uma tela restrita, com login. Esse atalho vai passar um determinado parâmetro para que se crie a sessão e não precise do Login.

Se o parâmetro for via url, o usuário pode copiar essa url, e usa-la diretamente no navegador, sem passar pelo atalho no sistema (regra de negócio), além de passar a terceiros.

Comment: Você poderia usar o Indy para dar o Post, e mandar o Windows abrir a URL de retorno com o ShellExec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema usando TWebBrowser:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Data: String;
    I: Integer;
    Flags, PostData, Headers: OleVariant;
begin

  Flags := navOpenInNewWindow;
  Data  := 'View={1B605F4E-A7C9-4B7B-98B7-5A2D2ADBD520}';
  PostData := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(Data)-1], varByte);
  for I := 1 to Length(Data) do PostData[I-1] := Ord(Data[I]);
  Headers := 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' + #10#13;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://localhost:49486/admin/Login.aspx', Flags, EmptyParam, PostData, Headers);

end;
```

O único detalhe é que ele abre por padrão no navegador Internet Explorer.

Comment: Se você vai abrir a URL de dentro da aplicação, não vai ter como fugir do IE (não sem alguma lib). Agora se você puder abrir com o navegador padrão da maquina, tem como fazer.

Comment: Para você entender, na requisição GET os parâmetros são passados via url, da forma como explicou na pergunta. No seu caso você precisa fazer uma requisição POST. Recomendo que faça isso usando os componentes Indy. Pesquise no Google por "delphi indy post MultipartFormDataStream" e encontrará muitas coisas... Boa sorte!